# how to get data to save from arrays inside array

Tags: php, laravel

i have form to make a bill for multiple products,
that form return request like this

```
  #parameters: array:5 [▼

  "quantity" => array:2 [▼
    0 => "1"
    1 => "2"
  ]
  "product" => array:2 [▼
    0 => "Mr. Jasen Beer,OliveDrab,XS"
    1 => "Carlotta Yundt"
  ]
  "date" => array:2 [▼
    0 => "2019-12-29"
    1 => "2019-12-29"
  ]
  "id" => array:2 [▼
    0 => "15"
    1 => "11"
  ]
]
}
```

i need to loop all arrays to make insert all at once 
thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to loop it like this, you will get the **array wrap every product's attributes**:

```php
$inserted_array = [];

foreach($parameters as $key => $values) {
    foreach($values as $index => $val) {
         $inserted_array[$index][$key] = $val;
    }
}

\DB::table('table_name')->insert($inserted_array);
```

And I found that there is `id` in your array, remember to make it fillable.